# How to find the optimal path for a line following maze bot?

Tags: algorithm, graph, mapping, depth-first-search

***This question was already posted in robotics stackexchange but i did not get any reply.
Moreover, this question is about solving a maze with some constraints, so its not limited to making a particular robot with uC and all.***

First let me explain the problem.

**This is a maze made only out of black lines on a white surface. The robot has only a few IR sensors which can sense the position of the line. No other sensory input is available.**

This is a maze with many self-loops and so a simple LSRB or equivalent algorithm wont work. The robot is supposed to learn the maze and then solve it as optimally as possible .

The above figure represent the possible intersections as all the paths are at 90deg to each other.

As far as my understanding goes, the robot will first scan how many nodes there are, and what their connections to each other is, thus effectively constructing the graph. Next, implement any shortest path algorithm and make your robot follow it.

However, the main problem that i cant get my head around is this:

**How will this blind robot know it isnt viewing the same node multiple times if it keeps coming back to the same point after getting caught in a loop?**

Also, please suggest good approaches to solving this problems along with any experience anybody has. How does one shot searching methods like DFS , Iterative deepeing DFS , hill climbing work in such scenarios ?

[image: arrow denotes the direction of motion]

Comment: Does the robot not know how far it's traveled, and which turns it's made?

Comment: yes it can know how far it has travelled and also it can keep track of number of turns made for each of the 4 cases .

Answer (score 0):

When it meets a crossing, the robot must keep a trace of the lanes it didn't take and backtrack later. In addition, it must be able to model the paths with enough accuracy to check that it is back in a place it has seen before.

Then I am not sure that there is a better strategy than

- traverse the lanes until you find the exit;
- every time you have a crossing, note the lane that you skip;
- when you are back at a known place, return to a skipped lane by the shortest route.

If the map is not known beforehand, you obviously cannot find the optimal path, unless by chance.

If there is no way to estimate the geometry, all you can do is random moves.